# Visual Studio localhost IIS Server Not Found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, iis-express

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET webforms website that I downloaded from an FTP server, but I'm running into problems when I try to build and run the project.

When I build and run the website, it opens my browser window, but adds "www." before the localhost address and I get a server not found error. I'm able to successfully build and run other websites, so I think I must have something wrong in the web.config or website properties. Here's a screenshot of my browser window:

[image: "WWW." was added to the address.]

- Visual Studio Version: 15.7.2
- IS Express: 10.0.1743

I tried changing the IIS port being used in the application.config file to see if that helped, but it gets replaced by a new site tag after I edit the original one. For example if my original port is 51060 and I change it to 51065 like this:

```
<sites>
<site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
<site name="mywebsite" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\me\Documents\mywebsite" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51065:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
<siteDefaults>
    <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
    <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
</siteDefaults>
<applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
<virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

The application.config file changes to:

```
<sites>
<site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
<site name="mywebsite" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\me\Documents\mywebsite" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51065:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
<site name="mywebsite(1)" id="3">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\me\Documents\mywebsite" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51060:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
<siteDefaults>
    <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
    <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
</siteDefaults>
<applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
<virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

**Thanks for any help.**

Comment: "www.localhost" is invalid, as there is no DNS record for it, and IIS Express has no corresponding mapping. Study computer network basics, and you will see why.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes. I understand that is invalid, but when I remove the "www." and try to navigate to http://localhost:port#, I am redirected to this "www." address.

Comment: Revert all your previous changes. Then check if any place in the code base tries to perform redirection. IIS Express by default won't perform such.

Comment: @ASP.NETHelpAccount check the application `web.config` file for any url rewrite rules causing the redirect to www url. Also, search in the code for any such redirection

Answer (score -1):

Right click on your web forms application project and then properties, navigate to the Web section, then look at the Servers section, and look at the Project Url that is being used, you can also mark the option Override application root URL if needed.

I hope it helps.

Comment: While researching for a fix to my problem, I came across answers like this, but when I right click on my website and navigate to "Properties Window" or "Properties Pages" I don't see a web section. The closest I can get is the Developer Web Server options, but I can't change the URL there, it's grayed out.

Comment: Ohhh what you have is a website not a web application that's why you don't have a properties window, try this 

**Method 3: Enable the Directory Browsing feature in IIS Express** 
in the following: 
[reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942062/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage)

Comment: Also you are not specifying which page to run, so right click in any .aspx file and then run the application.